# how to add custom word press regisration form in word press 3.5 with out module

Tags: login, user-registration

i want to add custom registration form in wordpress 3.5 ..with out module i tried few code samples in net seems to be not working with 3.5 properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create custom register page then you use in wp-users Table

```
wp_create_user();
```

It will create the user and if you want to add custom field then save that field data in wp-usermeta table using

```
update_user_meta();
```

and last if you want to add role to the user then use

```
$u = new WP_User( $user_ID);
$role_of_user= $u->roles[0];
$u->remove_role($role_of_user);
$u->add_role('your_role');
```